# Limit of distance between two random points in a unit-radius $n$-sphere

Tags: pr.probability, mg.metric-geometry

This is a companion contrast to [the earlier analogous question for unit $n$-cubes](https://mathoverflow.net/q/163294/6094),
where the answer (provided by several respondents) is $\infty$ .

> What is the limit, as $n \to \infty$, of the expected distance between two
>   points chosen uniformly at random within a unit-radius hypersphere
>   in $\mathbb{R}^n$, i.e., in the unit-radius $n$-ball?

Dividing OEIS [A093530](http://oeis.org/A093530) by [A093531](http://oeis.org/A093531) I
see that it appears to be approaching approximately $1.37$ for odd $n$, but I wonder if the
limit is actually known, either exactly or to significant precision?
I cannot quite extract an answer from the [MathWorld article](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BallLinePicking.html)...

This certainly provides a dramatic contrast between the $n$-cube and the $n$-sphere!

Comment: I'm not sure there's such a contrast between cubes and spheres.  In high dimensions a unit cube is vastly larger than a unit sphere, as measured by diameter or volume, so it's not as fair a comparison as the word "unit" suggests.

Comment: If instead we look at the ratio of expected distance to diameter, then for spheres the limit is asymptotically $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$, while for cubes it is (from Nate Eldredge's answer to the linked question) $\frac{1}{\sqrt{6}}$.  Is it known whether Spheres maximize this ratio, whether in finite dimensions or asymptotically?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Both points will be very close to (let's pretend: on) the surface with prob almost 1. Call the first point the north pole. By concentration of measure for the sphere, a randomly chosen second point is almost guaranteed to be almost on the equator, so the limit should be $\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: May I ask: Why can you assume that the first point is the north pole? Concentratoin of measure again?

Comment: I condition on the first point, and the sphere looks the same from any point.

Comment: Are you reading the question as "two points on the surface of the unit sphere", or ought this be overwhelmingly likely?

Comment: Yes, "sphere" (as opposed to "ball"), but even if it's the ball, almost all the volume is near the surface, so it won't matter.

Comment: Oh, I see! When I wrote "within a sphere" I meant "in the ball bounded by the sphere." I will clarify.

Comment: I should have known, after your first comment (sorry for the fake discussion)... Solution stays the same, though, by also applying the trivial concentration of measure near the surface first.

Comment: See also the later MO question: [Upper bound of the maximum average distance between $n$ points in a $d$-dimensional ball for $d\ll \log(n)$ and $n\gg 1$](https://mathoverflow.net/q/376821/6094).